# How can I do the equivalent of the following in Java

Tags: java, perl

I'm converting the following Perl script to Java. Please explain what it does and the best approach via Java.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use MIME::Base64;
use Convert::BinHex;

print encode_base64(pack "H*", "06d8f33b9c3dd94f8f45a5ef0bd54c63f0cd3113b7b5ebae79807041f7e2f8975352367266a926ea8a2a93ca");
```

Comment: If you don't know what that code does, why are you converting it to java?

Comment: @Falm - probably part of a job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though I don't know Perl I'd make an informed guess that it takes binary data in hexadecimal form (where each byte is represented by two characters in the range [0-9a-f]) and converts it to a [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string.

In Java, you use [`DatatypeConverter::parseHexBinary`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary%28java.lang.String%29) and [`DatatypeConverter::printBase64Binary`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte%5b%5d%29).

```
String hexData = "06d8f33b9c3dd94f8f45a5ef0bd54c63f0cd3113b7b5ebae79807041f7e2f8975352367266a926ea8a2a93ca";
String base64data = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(
        DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexData));
System.out.println(base64data);
```

Comment: Correct - and just to prove you were right, I ran the Perl script from the OP, and it output "BtjzO5w92U+PRaXvC9VMY/DNMRO3teuueYBwQffi+JdTUjZyZqkm6ooqk8o=", which is the exact same output from your Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

Base64.encodeBase64(string you want to encode.getBytes());
```